# Loop directory to return multiple PDF Files

Tags: c#, file, foreach, directory

I need to fill in pdf form fields using `itext7`. My logic is generating 1 file but i need it to generate all the PDFs placed inside the given folder, at a time. My working is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Job newJob)
{
    string path = MyServer.MapPath(@"\Files\");
    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path);

    foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.pdf"))
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(file.FullName))
        {
            var sourceFileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(file.FullName); 
            var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
            var pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(sourceFileStream), new PdfWriter(outputStream));
            PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, false);
            if (form != null)
            {
                IDictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetAllFormFields();
                PdfFormField toset;
                fields.TryGetValue("CustomerName", out toset);
                toset.SetValue(newJob.CustomerName);

                fields.TryGetValue("PropertyAddress", out toset);
                toset.SetValue(newJob.PropertyAddress);
                pdf.Close();
            }
            byte[] bytes = outputStream.ToArray();
            var OutputFile = File(bytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, file.FullName);
            return OutputFile;
        }  
    }
    return View();
}
```

As you notice, after returning the first `OutputFile`, program is quitting and not looping through the directory for the second pdf File to generate. Can you please show me ways to loop through the directory after the first `OutputFile` is ready.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you asking why `return` exits your loop? Well, that's what the keyword is for, to **immediately** leaveing a function.

Comment: What do you want to return, when your folder has multiple pdf-files? It's not really clear to me, what exactly you want to achieve here.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain, thank you for replying. Yes. I have placed 7 pdf files in the directory folder and I need my code to run for all 7 files and not exit after running the code for only 1 file as the current behavior.

Comment: Don't return anything from inside the loop, rather save results of all iterations e.g. into a `List` and return after loop is finished.

Comment: the question was what it should *return* in that case.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain i want all 7 pdf files to return

Comment: @Sinatr Thank you for replying. `List` of `FileResults`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `return OutputFile;` statement ends the current method, returning the result to the caller.

When doing so, it will also end `foreach` it is in, and the `if`, and everything.

What you coded here is returning the first file you created, or `View()` if you did not create any file at all.

What I really find interesting is that this code sample even compiles, because your method returns an `IActionResult` interface, which a `File`object dont implement.

The ActionResult types represent various HTTP status codes. Any non-abstract class deriving from ActionResult qualifies as a valid return type.

So: do not return the created File, create a real ActionResult instead.